# Dynamically building table rows, where in user can type in data using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When someone select a date range from a dropdown, for example

> 1/1/2017 - 1/7/2017

I want to paint

```
Date        Column1 Column2 Column3

1/1/2017    ----    ----    ----
1/2/2017
1/3/2017
1/4/2017
1/5/2017
1/6/2017
1/7/2017    ----    ----    ----
```

> The user will type in the text boxes (please assume "----" as text
>   boxes).

Similarly, when the date range gets changed, for example

> 2/2/2017 - 2/9/2017

```
Date        Column1 Column2 Column3

2/2/2017    ----    ----    ----
2/3/2017
2/4/2017
2/5/2017
2/6/2017
2/7/2017
2/8/2017
2/9/2017   ----     ----    ----
```

I have not used angular much,beginner here, i can use limitTo filter to limit 7 rows, any sample approaches?

Answer (score 0):

The ngRepeat is your friend here...

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

Take a look what happens in the `<pre>`-tag if you type in one of the inputs. Will this work for you?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in dateRange">
    <td>{{ x.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.input"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.input2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<pre>{{ dateRange | json }}</pre>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dateRange = [
      {
        date: '2/2/2017',
        name: 'Wonderfull Day'
      },
      {
        date: '2/3/2017',
        name: 'Bad Day'
      },
      {
        date: '2/4/2017',
        name: 'Better Day'
      }
    ];
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, displaying data , i am fine with it. I want create text boxes and ask the user to enter data.

Comment: Ok so the table rows you can create with the repeat right? Then for every row you can create the <td>[date]</td> <td>[input]</td> or am I missing something?

Comment: Date needs to be dynamically added, if my start date is 1/1/2017, the lines should paint 1/1/2017, 1/2/2017 etc. in every row, date should be a label value and other columns should be painted as text boxes, in which user types in.